# how to add language to my DSpace?

Tags: dspace

I want to add "arabic" to my DSpace.

I configure this file :

```
[dspace]/config/dspace.cfg
```

with this line:

```
webui.supported.locales = en, de, ar
```

Then I build Dspace and restart Tomcat.

But I can't find this file :

```
 "Messages.properties" at   
[dspace-src]/dspace/modules/jspui/src/main/resources/Messages.properties
```

and how German can appear on my DSpace wherever I can't find

```
"Messages_de.properties" at  
[dspace-src]/dspace/modules/jspui/src/main/resources/Messages_de.properties
```

Will I have other strange problems to customize my DSpace with arabic?

Answer (score 7):

I haven't seen a copy of the Arabic translation of all the "messages" for DSpace, but someone may have started one, or you can build it yourself. If you have to start on Arabic language from scratch, you can copy

`[dspace-source]/dspace-api/src/main/resources/Messages.properties`

to

`[dspace-source]/dspace/modules/src/main/resource/Messages_ar.properties`

You would then need to fill in the keys/values.

The reason that German language works, is that DSpace fetches language files from the internet through Maven.

Look at the SVN repo for all the languages (Arabic not available): 
[SVN link](http://scm.dspace.org/svn/repo/modules/dspace-api-lang/trunk/src/main/resources/)

If you need more help, its best to contact the dspace-tech mailing list. There is likely someone there who's solved this problem. And might have the Arabic message file.

Comment: I see there is an arabic translation available for XMLUI at: https://github.com/DSpace/dspace-xmlui-lang/blob/master/src/main/webapp/i18n/messages_ar.xml

Answer (score 1):

For deployed web application language files are in **dspace-api-lang-1.x.x.x.jar** file (it is actually archived folder and x.x.x depends on version you work with). You can find it in **[your JSPUI webapp location]/WEB-INF/lib** folder.

You can, actually, extract required file with localization to **[your JSPUI webapp location]/META-INF** folder and edit if you need.

If you want to work with that translations during development, just copy that file from deployed webapp (or in "target" subfolder after project build) to [dspace-src]/dspace/modules/jspui/src/main/resources/ and you'll be able to edit it in IDE or text editor (or whatever ...).